# understanding 3d transform detection code modenizer

Tags: javascript

i was just going through the code of modenizer , because i need to implement a little feature detection in my small online application . so the check i need is for `cssTransform3d` I.E to check for 3dTranforms ,if its available in the browser.

```
tests['csstransforms3d'] = function() {

    var ret = !!testPropsAll('perspective');

                  if ( ret && 'webkitPerspective' in docElement.style ) {

                  injectElementWithStyles('@media (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d){
                                              #modernizr{left:9px;position:absolute;height:3px;}
                                              }',
                  function( node, rule ) {
                      ret = node.offsetLeft === 9 && node.offsetHeight === 3;
                  });
    }
    return ret;
};
```

now check the callback function inside `injectElementWithStyles` , there are two params being passed , `node` and `rule` , who is passing these parameters ? i see nowhere in the global variable declaration that these variables are being declared.

The injectElementWithStles function is as follows ::

```
injectElementWithStyles = function( rule, callback, nodes, testnames ) {

  var style, ret, node, docOverflow,
      div = document.createElement('div'),
            body = document.body,
            fakeBody = body || document.createElement('body');

  if ( parseInt(nodes, 10) ) {
          while ( nodes-- ) {
          node = document.createElement('div');
          node.id = testnames ? testnames[nodes] : mod + (nodes + 1);
          div.appendChild(node);
      }
  }

            style = ['&#173;','<style id="s', mod, '">', rule, '</style>'].join('');
  div.id = mod;
      (body ? div : fakeBody).innerHTML += style;
  fakeBody.appendChild(div);
  if ( !body ) {
            fakeBody.style.background = '';
            fakeBody.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      docOverflow = docElement.style.overflow;
      docElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      docElement.appendChild(fakeBody);
  }

  ret = callback(div, rule);
    if ( !body ) {
      fakeBody.parentNode.removeChild(fakeBody);
      docElement.style.overflow = docOverflow;
  } else {
      div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
  }

  return !!ret;

},
```

now i am relatively new to js , yet i have tried making sense of both these functions , as far as i know a variable or parameter needs to be initialized/declared before being passed ,but i don't see either `node` or `rule` being declared , can somebody explain what is happening and what values do these variables take ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 1):

So, let me try to explain.

**Signature** for the `injectElementWithStyles` is `rule, callback, nodes, testnames` which means that those are the parameters it's expecting.

When that function is called, it's passing just `rule` and `callback`:

```
injectElementWithStyles(
'@media (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d){#modernizr{left:9px;position:absolute;height:3px;}}', function( node, rule ) {
 ret = node.offsetLeft === 9 && node.offsetHeight === 3;
});
```

So, bear in mind that the function is the second parameter to the `injectElementWithStyles` function. Note that the function being passed (the one that confuses you) is not being invoked just yet, it's being passed as a parameter to the `injectElementWithStyles`.

Within that function, the callback is called like this:

```
ret = callback(div, rule);
```

Which, as you see, matches the signature of the callback passed: That is, `div` is `node` and `rule` is... well... `rule`.

Is in that moment that the execution flow goes to the troubling function and `node` will have the value of `div` (declared in that function) and `rule` will hold the value of `rule` (declared in that function too)

Hope this clarifies!

---

Now, you may want to look at `Modernizr.addTest` which accepts a rule name and a function to be evaluated that must return true or false. So, in your app, let's say you want to test if you're in production:

```
Modernizr.addTest('production', function () {
    return window.isProduction;
});
```

That will add the class `production` to the HTML element if `window.isProduction` is `true` and `no-production` otherwise.

Comment: @Antonia , but what is the value of node and rule ? i don't see that being initilized anywhere !

Comment: `node` has the value of the variable `div` being declared inside the `injectElementWithStyles` function. And `rule` has the value of the variable `rule` being declared there too. That function you're referring to, is not going to be called until here: `ret = callback(div, rule);`

Comment: Added a bit more of content. I think what is confusing you is the fact that the function is not being called immediately. That function is just a parameter which `injectElementWithStyles` decides when to execute.

Comment: No problem! Glad it made sense. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved  your question!